# listbox binding not working as it should

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I bound (at least i think i did) data to a `ListBox` following a tutorial. The class element I want bound has data in it but i see nothing on the `ListBox` after some event. I have the following partial XAML:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="jukeBoxListBox" Height="227" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding FilePathList}"/>
```

In the WPF form cs file I have. Should i set to class `FolderItems` or its attr `filePathList`? Also should I use `ObservableCollection` instead of `list`?

```
InitializeComponent();    
FolderItems folderItems = new FolderItems();
this.DataContext = folderItems.FilePathList;
```

My data class:

```
class FolderItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    private ObservableCollection<String> _pathList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<String> FilePathList
    {
        get { return _pathList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _pathList)
            {
                _pathList = value;
                Notify("FilePathList");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need to mention that I change the `List` elements in a `Button` click event. Maybe the below is a part of the problem.

```
//in the event fItems is an instance of FolderItems   
var files = new ObservableCollection<string>();
ProcessFiles(of.SelectedPath, files);
fItems.FilePathList = files;
//...

    private void ProcessFiles(string path, ICollection<string> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(name => name.EndsWith(".mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            files.Add(file);    

        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            ProcessFiles(directory, files);

    }
```

I hail from Javaland and am brand new to C#. Please excuse my language.

Comment: You're ignoring the returned collection from calling `ProcessFiles` when looping over directories. You should pass the collection as method parameter to `ProcessFiles` and add filenames to always the same collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd change `List<string>` to `ObservableCollection<string>` ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)), your binding would get notified about changes in the list, e.g. when you add items.

Also, you must change the property name in the Notify call to `filePathList`.

And you should follow coding conventions for properties in .Net, which are usually written with a leading uppercase character. So your property would be `FilePathList`.

```
private ObservableCollection<String> pathList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<String> FilePathList
{
    get { return pathList; }
    set
    {
        if (value != pathList)
        {
            pathList = value;
            Notify("FilePathList"); // changed here
        }
    }
}
```

Change the binding to the renamed property:

```
<ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding FilePathList}"/>
```

---

See also [Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections) and [Using Collection Objects as a Binding Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#collections).

---

UPDATE

Your `ProcessFiles` method should be written as shown below to enable recursion.

```
private void ProcessFiles(string path, ICollection<string> files)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(name => name.EndsWith(".mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
        files.Add(file);
    }

    foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        ProcessFiles(directory, files);
    }
}
```

And be called like this:

```
var files = new ObservableCollection<string>();
ProcessFiles(of.SelectedPath, files);

var folderItems = new FolderItems();
folderItems.FilePathList = files;
DataContext = folderItems;
```

Or if you need to access the `FolderItems` object later (perhaps in some event handler) you might get it back from the `DataContext`:

```
DataContext = new FolderItems();

...

var folderItems = DataContext as FolderItems;
ProcessFiles(of.SelectedPath, folderItems.FilePathList);
```

Comment: i tried those but nothing happened  in the listbox. I edited the question to latest form.

Comment: Done the changes. `fItems.FilePathList = files;` fills the FilePathList but nothing shows up on the listbox.

Comment: And did you assign `fItems` to the MainWindow's `DataContext`? In your question you're creating something called `folderItems`.

Comment: Right below, `InitializeComponent()` there is `FolderItems folderItems = new FolderItems();   this.DataContext = folderItems.FilePathList;`

Comment: Ah, another problem here: You must set the `DataContext` to `folderItems`, not `folderItems.FileListPath`. You should have seen binding error messages in Visual Studio output window when you run you program in debugger. See my edit

Comment: Thanks it finally worked. Btw the code looks much better now. Just to clear everything up; If I want to bind something. I create a class, set every parameter of the class I want bound, then DataContext the class itself and then I'm on my way. Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this. 
I search for dll files insteed of mp3. you can change the pattern as you need.

```
     public class FolderItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



            //Temp Data
            public FolderItems()
            {


  //Add System.windows.Form assampbly. 
            var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FilePathList = ProcessFiles(dialog.SelectedPath);


                ////var directories = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows\\").GetFiles().Select(x => x.Name);

                //foreach (var file in directories)
                //{
                //    FilePathList.Add(file);
                //}
    }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<String> ProcessFiles(string path)
            {
                string[] directories;
                ObservableCollection<String> fileList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
                var files = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.dll").Select(x => x.Name); //Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(name => name.EndsWith(".mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                fileList = new ObservableCollection<String>(files.ToList<String>());


                //your processing further
                //directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
                //foreach (string directory in directories)
                //{
                //    // Process each directory recursively
                //    ProcessFiles(directory);
                //}

                return fileList;
            }

            protected void Notify(string propertyName)
            {
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

            private ObservableCollection<String> _pathList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            public ObservableCollection<String> FilePathList
            {
                get { return _pathList; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _pathList)
                    {
                        _pathList = value;
                        Notify("FilePathList");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: The `ProcessFiles` method is in a WPF code. The point was to get the user to select a folder (from the WPF window). Get the files from the selected folder, then set the list in to the  `FolderItems` class which would have a `ObservableCollection` to be bound to a listbox over at the wpf part.

Comment: @Jodha Where is the recursion into subdirectories?

Comment: I checked again and this `fItems.FilePathList = files;` is properly set on both sides. files, is full of 33 useful objects, also fItems.FilePathList is also the same. I can just do `someListBox.ItemSource= whatever` and get the listbox to show stuff but i'm trying to seperate the view and on the way learn binding wpf style. This is possible in wpf right?

Comment: I fixed the code according to Clemens' suggestion. I don't think it's recursion because, i choose a folder without anymore folders in it with only mp3 files. I can see the files in every variable above but not in the listbox:D